# Inexplicable offsets in some very basic HTML

Tags: html, css

I sometimes find myself in the situation that there are some offsets in basically very simple HTML/CSS which I don't comprehend.

Here's one [example](https://jsfiddle.net/g1n4kckz/):

```html
<div style="width: 100%; height: 92px;">
  <image src="https://www.google.at/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" width="272px" height="92px"></image>
  <a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
</div>
```

[image]

Where does the additional vertical offset come from?

The "only" solution I found so far was to use a `div` with a `background-image` instead of the `image` element...

Comment: Use `vertical-align: middle` on `<a>` and `<img`. Default value is `baseline`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `inline` and `inline-block` elements are aligned according to `baseline` of their parent. Use `vertical-align` to change this behavior.

```css
a,
img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 100%; height: 92px;">
  <img src="https://www.google.at/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" width="272px" height="92px">
  <a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `link` should have a `bottom` vertical  align, by default it is `baseline`

```css
a {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

img{
  vertical-align: bottom;
  }
```

```html
<div style="width: 100%; height: 92px;">
  <img src="https://www.google.at/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" width="272px" height="92px">
  <a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For all `inline` type `display`s whether it is `inline`, `inline-block`, `inline-flex` and the like, DOM elements flow like text -

1. Note that there is some implicit space between the *inline* elements horizontally (that varies with `font-size`)
2. The vertical-alignment defaults to `baseline` - see how it aligns to the *baseline* of the text in the demo below:

   ```css
   .wrapper {
     border: 1px solid;
   }
   .wrapper > * {
     display: inline-flex;
     border: 1px solid;
     height: 100px;
     width: 100px;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div class="wrapper">
     <div></div>
     <div>
       <h1>kjk</h1>
     </div>
   </div>
   ```

**Solution**:

You can use `vertical-align:middle` to align the *inline* elements vertically.

```css
div > * {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 100%; height: 92px;">
  <image src="https://www.google.at/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" width="272px" height="92px"></image>
  <a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
</div>
```