# place paragraph under the first paragraph

Tags: html, css, display

I'm trying to place text after another text but both are aligning in same line. Please help me with this.

```html
<a class="text-dark" href="">become a driver</a>
<a class="text-dark" href="">driver</a>
```

Comment: that's because `a` in inline... add `display: block` to it... read [more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40630148/inexplicable-offsets-in-some-very-basic-html/40630355#40630355)

Comment: Nope i'm using multiple links like that in a division. what should i do with a division.

Comment: So add `<br>`, this is basic HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your `a` tag or `.text-dark` class `display:block`

```css
a {
display:block
}
```

```html
<a class="text-dark" href="">become a driver</a>
<a class="text-dark" href="">driver</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a couple of ways you can do this, here are a few:

```css
.text-dark {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a class="text-dark" href="">become a driver</a>
<a class="text-dark" href="">driver</a>

<a href="">become a driver</a><br/>
<a href="">driver</a>
```